# I'm trying to grep a pattern in multiple files and print the corresponding matching lines to different new files.

Tags: regex, perl

I tried it for 1 file but the output it's giving is : HASH(0x61fff0). Please suggest where i'm going wrong.

```
use File::Grep qw( fgrep );
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file="outfile1.txt";
open(FL,">","$file");
my @matches = fgrep { /"first"/ } glob "./file1.txt";
print FL $_ foreach @matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is only used to match a particular keyword, to split and then print the matching pattern..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file="outfile1.txt";
open(FL,"$file");
my @f=<FL>;
my @matches = grep {m/first/g} @f;
chomp,print "$_\n", foreach(@matches);
```

Comment: Why you used the `@sp`?

Comment: yeah.! its match `first` pattern in that file. print that lines.

Comment: use `chomp,print "$_\n", foreach(@matches);` instead of `my @sp= split("",$_), print $_ , foreach(@matches);` Don't use the unwanted variable.

Comment: Try to avoid grep for extract the lines from a file. Use `while loop` instead of storing the all element in an array. :)

Comment: @mkHun Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use File::Grep::fmap instead of File::Grep::fgrep

```
use File::Grep qw( fgrep fmap );
...
my @matches = fmap { /"first"/ ? ($_) : () } glob "./file1.txt";
```

**OR** use more complicated code for printing File::Grep::fgrep results

```
foreach my $match (@matches){
  my $filename =  $match->{filename};
  my $count = $match->{count};
  foreach $pos (sort{$a<=>$b} keys %{$match->{matches}}) {
     print FL $match->{$pos};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file= "outfile1.txt";
open (FL,'>$file');

my @glob_matches =  glob ("./file1.txt");

my @grep_matches = grep(/first/, @glob_matches);

foreach my $filtered_files (@grep_matches){

print FL $filtered_files."\n";

}
```